# Change Alfresco versioning baseline

Tags: alfresco, versioning

Here's something I've been struggling with for months...

I'd like to use Alfresco to manage our teams' internal documentations, but its default versioning is a major drawback to us: it stats at 1.0, we need it to start at 0.1.
I've been searching all over the web for an answer, even trying to change Alfresco's code, unsuccessfuly.
I've found what seems to be a solution (https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-15082) but I can't find any trace of such a feature in recent versions of Alfresco...

Manually changing version would help too...

Can someone help?

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you currently using?

Comment: I use version 5.0.d

Comment: Bad news - I've checked the relevant `VersionServiceImpl` code and it's still hard-coded to create a Major version number (i.e. 1.0) when first doing versioning stuff to an un-versioned node. You might be able to write an `OnCreateVersionPolicy` class with monkeys with the version number as it gets added, but it's been a few years since I touched that code so I can't be certain...